# Why does "copy" is called "yank" in Vim?

Tags: vim, copy, terminology, yank

[yank](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yank):

> to pull on something with a quick vigorous movement

How does "yank" correspond to the copy functionality in Vim?

Comment: Because C was taken by delete lines :P

Comment: This question is closed as off-topic in the programming section, and a similar question was closed as off-topic in the English section. Stackoverflow is so Stackoverflow.

Comment: Interestingly, ["yanking"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Yanking.html) means quite the opposite operation (e.g. pasting) in Emacs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The text is pulled (yanked) into the register for later use